# Phantom.js callback Reference errors when refactoring Phantom.js on Node.js/Express.js to avoid "callback hell"

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have this crazy large block of code that functions, but which I am hoping to refactor properly. With accordance to [Callback Hell](http://callbackhell.com/), I tried to break it down into non-anonymous functions and seperate those functions from the central code.

However, I am running into the problem that a lot of the different sections of the code are dependent on using the others as parameters. The first error message I received in the sequence is `ReferenceError: page is not defined`

The un-refactored code is:

```
function startMyFunction(firstLayerUrl) {
        phantom.create(function (ph) {
            ph.createPage(function (page) {
                var main_file=firstLayerUrl
                page.open(main_file, function (status) {
                    var linkArray=[];
                    page.evaluate(function (linkArray) {
                        for (var i=0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('a').length; i++) {
                            linkArray.push(document.getElementsByTagName('a')[i].href)
                        }
                        return linkArray;
                    }
                    , function finished(result) {
                        linkArray = result;
                        runEmailLoop(linkArray);
                        page.close()
                        ph.exit();
                    },linkArray);
                });
            });
        }, {
            dnodeOpts: {
                weak: false
            }
        });
}
```

The attempted refactored code is:

```
function runFirstLayer(firstLayerUrl) {
    phantom.create(function (ph) {
        ph.createPage(function (page) {
            var main_file=firstLayerUrl
            page.open(main_file, openIndexPage(status));
        });
    }, {
        dnodeOpts: {
            weak: false
        }
    });
}

function openIndexPage (status) {
    var linkArray=[];
    page.evaluate(evaluatePage(linkArray), finished(result),linkArray);
}

function evaluatePage(linkArray) {
    for (var i=0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('a').length; i++) {
        linkArray.push(document.getElementsByTagName('a')[i].href)
    }
    return linkArray;
}

function finished(result) {
    linkArray = result;
    runEmailLoop(linkArray);
    page.close()
    ph.exit();
}
```

How can I pass the various dependencies on, such as `page`, `status`, since I have tried passing page but then get another error `ReferenceError: document is not defined`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is belongs on codereview.stackexchange

Comment: @GeorgeJempty: No, it does not. The code is not working.

Comment: I went by "re-factoring" in the title.  Refactoring is the process of improving *working* code.  My vote to close may be wrong, but you too may want to think of improving the question title.

Comment: Maybe: `Phantom.js callback Reference errors`

Answer (score 0):

You need to *pass* the functions, not call them:

```
page.open(main_file, openIndexPage);
/* instead of
page.open(main_file, openIndexPage(status));
*/
```

and

```
page.evaluate(evaluatePage, finished, linkArray);
/* instead of
page.evaluate(evaluatePage(linkArray), finished(result),linkArray);
*/
```

There are no `status`, `linkArray`, or `result` values in your code - they are *parameters* of the function definitions.

Comment: I passed the functions, removing the parameters as you said, but I'm still getting the error message `page is not defined` inside of `openIndexPage`: http://jsfiddle.net/xhx7ggLf/1/

Comment: Have you considered using http://www.nightmarejs.org/. It is higher level API over PhantomJS to avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: @codemonkey I was hoping to use nightmarejs originally, but unfortunately could not because of the `weak` module, and something being messed up on my system, such that I need to include `dnodeOpts: {weak: false }` after all of my phantom page opens, but I appreciate you comment, especially given the time of year.

Comment: @maudulus: Oh, right. You might try to use `this` instead of `page` in the `open()` handler, if that doesn't work you'll have to nest that function as well (move it into the closure). Or pass `page` explicitly, which would be cumbersome.